# After I Disabled the Driver Signature Verification, My PC says "Unknown Device" for my Android

Tags: windows-10, drivers, android

For installing custom ROMs on my Android device using SP Flash Tool, it is necessary to Disable the Driver Signature Verification for installing new drivers. These drivers are for recognizing the Android device in off condition.

After the completion of my work when I attached my device via USB cable for transferring some files, it simply doesn't recognize my device.

Other USB options like USB Tethering Works fine, but the file transfer option doesn't work.  And also it says Unknown Device in the Windows Device Manager.

My device works fine in other PCs and Laptops.

Comment: The driver is what Windows uses along with what data the device itself sends to identify the device.  An unsigned driver not having this information is to be expected.

Comment: Will you please help me to solve this issue.....??

Comment: When somebody knows the answer to your question they will submit it.   Consider earning enough reputation to place a bounty on the question.